# Grails dependency error-only looks in grailsCentral not other repos

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Grails 2.5...

I have a plugin in an SVN repository.

Here is the build config (minus authentication credentials)....

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // maven or ivy

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
   inherits("global") {
    // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
    // excludes 'ehcache'
}
log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility
repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    grailsCentral()

    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()

    mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"

    mavenRepo name:"*********", root: "*********************"

}
 plugins {

   runtime ':org-calendar-viewer:0.7.9'

}
```

But I always get a dependency resolve error it could not find the plugin at grailsCentral. Of course it couldn't the plugin is in a different repo. Is grailsCentral the last place it looks? Or the first place it looks?

```
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
```

I tried commenting out the grails repos and then it fails as

```
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact  in mavenCentral (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
```

So it seems it is throwing an error after only checking one(first) location?

Comment: Have you tried a `grails dependency-report`?

Comment: Also, add --info, --debug and --stacktrace to make sure you're seeing everything.

Comment: yes, dependency report just says that org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not find artifact... in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:384)